# A use of the word 'si' following the word 'savoir'

Tags: si

I came across this passage in a story by Blaise Cendrars from 1937:

> Maman avait préparé des sucreries. Vous savez si elle est gourmande, maman, et moi aussi, mais c'est fou ce que le petit sacristain aime les sucreries au miel.

I was surprised to see the word *si* after *savez* rather than *que*. Is there an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a very rare use of the adverb *si*. What would be more usual :

> *Vous savez [comme](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comme) elle est gourmande [...]* (You know how fond of food she is)

[TLFi **Si**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/si/1):  **I.- A.- 1. b) Rem.**

> Remarque *Si* adverbe d'intensité modifie un adjectif ou un adverbe (ou bien un participe); il est exceptionnel avec un verbe ou un syntagme prépositionnel: *Comment se peut-il que je sois un être si sensible et si vulnérable, et à la fois si à l'abri des assauts des importuns, si possédant son bonheur et sa tranquillité* (Ponge, Parti pris, 1942, p. 30).

Comment: ça me semble tout à fait équivalent à "vous savez combien elle est gourmande" ou encore "vous savez à quel point elle est gourmande". J'ai également parcouru toutes les entrée du TLFi pour si, et aucune ne semble correspondre exactement à cet usage.

Comment: @XouDo Oui, ce sont tous deux des équivalents de *comme* ici. Cet usage de *combien* est plus soutenu et me semble un peu démodé.